# PHP Zend is always redirecting to index page in IIS

Tags: php, iis, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a site build in PHP with ZendFramework on a IIS server, but it is always redirecting to the index page, it doesn't matter what the URL says. In apache it is working fine, but I need it in IIS.

This is my httpaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

and my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Zend Standard Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?route={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The page is http://stamati.com.ar, you can try any link there but the result will be always the same

Comment: You shouldn't be appending a query string `index.php?route=foo` just to index.php; e.g `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />`

Comment: I made this change but it is not working :( .. The web.config should be at the same level than application, public, etc, right?

Comment: This is the webpage http://stamati.com.ar/sistemasderiego you can try any link and you will be redirected always to the same page